# Dynamic SAX Parser for UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoded XML

Tags: java, android, xml, encoding, sax

I am developing an app for Android where I have to parse different XML files. Most of them are encoded in UTF-8, but a few may be encoded in ISO-8859-1.

```
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  ...
  in = con.getInputStream();
  InputSource is = new InputSource(in);
  ...
  parser.parse(is, handler);
```

My code for handling the input looks like above. The `java` documentation says about the `InputSource`:

> If there is no character stream, but there is a byte stream, the parser will use that byte stream, using the encoding specified in the InputSource or else (if no encoding is specified) autodetecting the character encoding using an algorithm such as the one in the XML specification.

I am passing in a `ByteStream` and I am don't specify an encoding, so according to the documentation the encoding should be auto detected. But it doesn't. All files that are encoded in UTF-8 are fine, but the ISO-8859-1 ones are not (I am getting a `Parser Expat... Exception for some invalid characters`). If I set the encoding of the `InputSource` manually to "ISO-8859-1" it behaves the other way round.

How can I solve this? I searched Google and `Stackoverflow` for hours, but not finding a solution. I also tried to pass a `CharacterStream` to the `InputSource`, but some characters `(äöüÄÖÜß)` in the ISO-8859-1 files are still displayed as "?" in my app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution depends on the exact cause of your problem. If you retrieve an XML document over HTTP, the encoding may also be specified in the Content-Type response header and not necessarily in the XML document itself. If that is the case and the XML libraries in Android are correctly implemented (I have no way to check here if the Content+Type header is evaluated), you should be able to create an InputSource with the URL directly `new InputSource("http://...");` instead.

If the encoding is not set in the HTTP header and not specified in the XML prologue, the parser operates correctly if it assumes UTF-8 encoding (as mandated by the XML specification). The autodetection mentioned in the documentation does not mean that the parser actually looks into the document content to make an assumption on the encoding, but means that it checks the encoding attribute of the XML stream. If the encoding attribute is missing, it defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: The similar problem to undeclared encoding is misdeclared encoding, so he will still have to try catch regardless.

Comment: The encoding parameter is set either to "UTF-8" or to "ISO-8859-1". But it seems that this information is not processed by the SAX parser / the InputSource. I retrieve the XML over HTTP. But checking the Content-Type of the response is a good idea. I will try this.

Comment: I ended up checking the Content-Type of the HTTP Header. If the charset is "ISO-8859-1" i set the encoding of the InputSource. Otherwise i don't set the encoding and the default "UTF-8" is used. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check if there are characters which are not in the old ascii set and reencode the string if there seems to be UTF-8 chars:

```
String output=new String(input.getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8");
```

That line takes the ISO-8859-1 and converts it to utf-8 which is used by Java.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to use UTF-8, and if the parser exception for invalid byte is thrown, attempt to reparse it as Windows-1252. 1252 because I doubt you will see anyone using the ISO-8859-1 C1 characters where as you will see people using Windows 1252 characters and claim it is ISO-8859-1 all the time.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to let SAX decide about encoding, it will know it from XML declaration encoding attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Note: if there is no xml declaration, which is legal, then encoding is assumed to be UTF-8

If you use byte stream InputSource, as in your example, and do not set InputStream encoding explicitly then SAX will take encoding from XML

**UPDATE**

Try this test. It writes xml string to 1.xml file in iso-8859-1. Then SAX parses it and prints root element text (it is only one character 'ä'). SAX is supposed to undestand that 1.xmk uses iso-8859-1 otherwise output will be distorted

```
String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><root>ä</root>";
OutputStreamWriter wrt = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
        "1.xml"), "iso-8859-1");
wrt.write(xml);
wrt.close();
SAXParserFactory sf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser p = sf.newSAXParser();
p.parse(new FileInputStream("1.xml"), new DefaultHandler() {
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println((int)ch[start]);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(ch, start, length));
    }
});
```

See output

```
228
ä
```

It is correct. SAX undestands that XML encoding = 'iso-8859-1'.

Comment: What do you mean with "let SAX decide"? All the XML files have an encoding attribute. I also thougt that the InputSource will decide about the encoding based on the encoding attribute. But it doesn't. Do you have any other idea how to handle this?

Comment: Sax cannot detect the currient encoding. It is ignoring any encoding settings in a xml header. If the encoding is wrong you must correct it yourself. See also my answer about that.

Comment: ä is 229 (0xE5) After you got your XML from parser, find this letter in debugger and check if it is 229 or not

Comment: Well the reason is that java normally works with utf-8. If your input file has another endcoing (which could happen) you need to reencode the file.

Comment: Thanks for your test. But I retrieve the XML over HTTP and i can't write a temporary file.

Comment: This is just a test to understand how SAX determines XML encoding, if you understand it you will solve your puzzle

Comment: I understand it totally. But the fact is that in my XML file there is the encoding attribute "ISO-8859-1" and some characters are displayed wrong. This is driving me crazy, because it should work in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know how you did this Evgeniy but i'm getting an exception after executing this code: "not well-formed (invalid token)"